# F# Equivalent to C#'s "extern alias"

Tags: f#, alias, extern

Anyone knows the F# equivalent to C#'s "extern alias" statement as described here? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2005/11/30/c-2-0-using-different-versions-of-the-same-dll-in-one-application/

I need to use two versions of a dll bearing the same name, but VS IDE does not allow me to add more than one.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's possible.

The language spec doesn't mention it, and the `--reference` compiler option to `fsc.exe` doesn't accept an aliased reference (despite [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/compiler-options) calling it equivalent to the C# compiler option).

If you really need this functionality, wrapping `extern alias` uses in a C# project and referencing that project from F# seems to be your safest bet. Alternatively load one or both of the dlls dynamically using `Assembly.LoadFrom`.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Seems like the latter is easier though, since the former solution will comprise 4 dll's - one for each of the two wrappers and then the underlying dll's, correct?

Comment: I was thinking two underlying dlls, then the C# wrapper using extern alias and exposing functionality from both, then the F# dll that consumes it. If the other solution works for you, that's fine as well.

Comment: To clarify the previous comment, it's not possible to "launder" the alias through C# - it will be local to the C# project in which the alias is defined. But you can expose the functionality to F# through C# wrapper classes.